# How to get request body in post Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I have an application that makes a POST request on submitting the form. But when the request is on the server, I cannot get the body of the request.

This is my ReactJS code:

```
const onSubmit = async event => {
  try {
    event.preventDefault()
    const response = await fetch('/api/auth/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
    })
    const result = await response.json()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

return (
  <>
    <h1>Authorisation</h1>
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input name="email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      <input name="password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} type="password"/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </>
)
```

In my backend I have Express:

```
app.use(express.json())

const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body)              // here is always {}
    const {email, password} = req.body
    /*some code*/
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Login error: ' + e)
  }
}

router.post('/login', login)
app.use(router)
```

Comment: Can you post complete code from express server? where you defined the route /login?

Comment: Front end code looks fine. Please post complete express side server code. I think you are missing something over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you are using `no-cors` mode . When you use that mode , it limits certain headers.

For example this type of mode only lets the `Content-Type` become `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

I suggest you just use `cors` mode so you can use `application/json`

Comment: I see, I changed the type of cors mode, thanks. But it didn't help, there is the same output

Comment: Interesting, can you get rid of the mode and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, there is no changes

Comment: Hey Mike, can you show us your react `useState` hooks for the email and password?

Comment: Idk why it did not working in the previous time, now its all working wery good, thank you